# hardcoded string "row three", should use @string resource

Tags: android, exception, internationalization

**I'm a beginner android developer , I was trying to run this Linear Layout in eclipse :**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

  <LinearLayout
      android:orientation="horizontal"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:layout_weight="1">
      <TextView
          android:text="red"
          android:gravity="center_horizontal"
          android:background="#aa0000"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:layout_weight="1"/>
      <TextView
          android:text="green"
          android:gravity="center_horizontal"
          android:background="#00aa00"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:layout_weight="1"/>
      <TextView
          android:text="blue"
          android:gravity="center_horizontal"
          android:background="#0000aa"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:layout_weight="1"/>
      <TextView
          android:text="yellow"
          android:gravity="center_horizontal"
          android:background="#aaaa00"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:layout_weight="1"/>
  </LinearLayout>

  <LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1">
    <TextView
        android:text="row one"
        android:textSize="15pt"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
    <TextView
        android:text="row two"
        android:textSize="15pt"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
    <TextView
        android:text="row three"
        android:textSize="15pt"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
    <TextView
        android:text="row four"
        android:textSize="15pt"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
  </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

And, I noticed :
1) yellow line under **`android:text="Yellow"`**
2) yellow line under **`android:text="row four"`**
the Triangle warn says `[I18N] Hardcoded string "Yellow", should use @string resource "`
and same for the rest of the warnings.Any suggestion?

Answer (score 135, accepted):

It is not good practice to hard code strings into your layout files.  You should add them to a string resource file and then reference them from your layout.

This allows you to update every occurrence of the word "Yellow" in all layouts at the same time by just editing your strings.xml file.

It is also extremely useful for supporting multiple languages as a separate strings.xml file can be used for each supported language.

example:
XML file saved at res/values/strings.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="yellow">Yellow</string>
</resources>
```

This layout XML applies a string to a View:

```
<TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="@string/yellow" />
```

Similarly colors should be stored in colors.xml and then referenced by using @color/color_name

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="Black">#000000</color>
</resources>
```

Comment: (out of scope) also, it looks like a table somehow. may be a tablelayout would be more appropriate. moreover, textsize in pt in discouraged. sp are more flexible.

Comment: Why is it @string/... and not @strings/...?

Comment: You are referencing a single string. Why would it be plural?

Comment: @Kuffs: If app is monolingual, and small Toasts like "Please enter value less than 100" needs to be shown, should we still follow _String Resource_ methodology?

Comment: I would as it makes the code cleaner and all your strings are in one place should you ever decide to add a new language in the future. At the end of the day though, it is recommendation not a rule.

Answer (score 14):

You must create them under
strings.xml

```
<string name="close">Close</string>
```

You must replace and reference like this

```
android:text="@string/close"/>
```

Do not use @strings even though the XML file says strings.xml or else it will not work.

Comment: @CroiOS Great English

Answer (score 11):

> It is not good practice to hard code strings into your layout files/ code. You should add them to a string resource file and then reference them from your layout.

1. This allows you to update every occurrence of the same word in all
   layouts at the same time by just editing your `strings.xml` file.
2. It is also extremely useful for `supporting multiple languages` as a
   separate `strings.xml file` can be used for each supported language
3. the actual point of having the `@string` system please read over the
   [localization](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html) documentation. It allows you to easily locate text in
   your app and later have it translated.
4. Strings can be internationalized easily, allowing your application
   to `support multiple languages with a single application package file`
   (APK).

**Benefits**

- Lets say you used same string in 10 different locations in the code.
  What if you decide to alter it? Instead of searching for where all it
  has been used in the project you just change it once and changes are
  reflected everywhere in the project.
- Strings don’t clutter up your application code, leaving it clear and
     easy to maintain.

Answer (score 4):

You can go to Design mode and select "Fix" at the bottom of the warning. Then a pop up will appear (seems like it's going to register the new string) and voila, the error is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

A good practice is write text inside String.xml

example:

String.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="yellow">Yellow</string>
</resources>
```

and inside layout:

```
<TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="@string/yellow" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the multiple language special case, what is wrong with the global find & replace approach as used in almost every other environment?

The 'one place' argument seems spurious. Changing a string of 'yellow' would not affect another of e.g: 'yellow paint'!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).