# Hardcoded string "Test", should use @string resource

Tags: android-layout

Here is my code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    
   
    <TextView
   
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/ref"    
     />
   
    <TextView
   
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Test"
     />
 
</LinearLayout>
```

I don't want to use string in the second test. What should I do?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No problem that you are using the string hardcoded or not. 
If you want further information you could look: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8743887/1517996

strings.xml

```
<resources>
    <string name="Test">Test</string> 
<resources>
```

and use it lin layout file like

```
<TextView

    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/Test"
 />
```

Comment: I already saw that link but i dont want any error on my code :/ is there any way to avoid this error ?

Comment: this is not an error, this is a warning. If you dont want this warning you should implement your "Test" string in strings.xml as <string name="Test">Test</string> and use it like <TextView

    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/Test"
 /> please see my edited post

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want this **warning** to bother you specifically on this View, you can use tools:ignore xml attribute to suppress it.

```
<TextView
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:text="@string/Test"
  tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />
```

Note that you can also add it to a parent element to suppress warnings on its children.

Answer (score 0):

You can use hardcoded value, it's fine. If you want to remove the warning, you can go to Eclipse -> preference -> Android -> Lint Error Checking and look for "Hardcoded Text". Set it to ignore then Apply.