# Why is using string literals in Android discouraged? What other/better alternatives are available?

Tags: java, android, string, string-literals

I know that using string literals in Android is discouraged but I do not know why. I also would like to know what possible ways can get round this problem.

Answer (score 6):

It's not necessarily a problem, just a warning. Android encourages the use of the strings resource file where possible but you certainly can hard-code strings and have it work correctly.

See this question/answers: [what's wrong with hardcoded string in android xml file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12634211/whats-wrong-with-hardcoded-string-in-android-xml-file)

Answer (score 6):

This isn't an Android-specific issue. It is a "best practice" for programming in general. It is always a good idea to put strings and other "localizable" data into separate files (properties files, resources, etc.). This makes localization into other languages much easier.