# android studio app text format

Tags: java, android

can anyone tell me what's wrong with this line of code ?

[image]

```
 public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    float x = event.values[0];
    float y = event.values[1];
    float z = event.values[2];

    textX.setText("X : " + (int) x + " rad/s");
    textY.setText("Y : " + (int) y + " rad/s");
    textZ.setText("Z : " + (int) z + " rad/s");
 }
};
```

Comment: the image i added above describes exactly the problem

Comment: What is the exact problem ?

Answer (score 1):

That is a warning, because you are hardcoding Strings in your code. That is not a really a problem, it is just discouraged, since it makes it harder to make your app multi-language.

Also, all the reasons for the warning and the kind of problems you can have are actually in the image you added.

You can also check this questions:

[Why is using string literals in Android discouraged? What other/better alternatives are available?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29501520/why-is-using-string-literals-in-android-discouraged-what-other-better-alternati)

[what's wrong with hardcoded string in android xml file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12634211/whats-wrong-with-hardcoded-string-in-android-xml-file)

Answer (score 0):

To me, your problem is that you are using '.setText()' on a concatenation that isn't all of String type.  You insert an (int) right in the middle of it.  Instead of "(int) x", you should use "x.toString()" or so.