# Unable to find reason- Error:(40) Error parsing XML: not well-formed (invalid token)

Tags: android, xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.android.musicplayer.MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/title"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:textSize="40sp"/>

 <Button
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
     android:id="@+id/button"
     android:text=">>"/>
  <Button
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
      android:layout_toRightOf="@id/button"
      android:id="@+id/button2"
      android:text="||"
      />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/button2"
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:text="<"
        />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/button3"
        android:text="||"
       />
    <SeekBar
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/button"
        android:id="@+id/seekBar"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="Small Text"
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_above="@id/seekBar"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/textView"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@id/textView" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="Small Text"
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_above="@id/seekBar"
        android:layout_alignRight="@id/button4"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@id/button4" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/textView2"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

I am also etting an error : 
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.

> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/home/dell/Android/Sdk/build-tools/23.0.2/aapt'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

Comment: replace `android:text="<" ` with `android:text="&lt;" ` or use string resource as per IntelliJ Amiya answer

Answer (score 2):

**Hardcoded string “<” & >>, should use @string resource**

Got it

Problem here

```
 android:text="<"  
 android:text=">>"
```

What should you do

```
android:text="@string/Your_String_Name"
```

Then

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="Your_String_Name">&lt;</string> // For < Sign 
</resources>
```

Courtesy goes https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references

> [hardcoded string "row three", should use @string resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8743349/hardcoded-string-row-three-should-use-string-resource)

Comment: it is written as text see carefully @IntelliJ Amiya

Comment: no that's correct you have to add these symbols in strings.xml and moreover why are you using symbols for music playback controls and not images??